# i have some login issue! would like some advice C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (username.Text == "" && password.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and Password");
}

if (!File.Exists(username.Text + ".txt"))
{
    err.SetError(username, "Username not exist"); //sets the error
    //MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Username");
}
else
{
    err.SetError(username, ""); //clears the error
    err.SetError(password, "");
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(username.Text + ".txt");
    string pass = tr.ReadLine();
    if (pass == password.Text)
    {
        app.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        err.SetError(password, "Password Incorrect");
        // MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Password");
    }
```

The issue I have occured when I tested the login with empty username and empty password, both error warning of username and message box that says "please enter username and password" show. How do I solve this so that when enter nothing will show the message box? And when user enter incorrect username or password, the warning will show for either?

I'm currently using C# Windows Forms.

Comment: What is the issue again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put return

Try this :

```
        if (username.Text == "" && password.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and Password");
            return;
        }

        if (!File.Exists(username.Text + ".txt"))
        {
            err.SetError(username, "Username not exist"); //sets the error
            //MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Username");
        }
        else
        {
           err.SetError(username, ""); //clears the error
            err.SetError(password, "");
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(username.Text + ".txt");
            string pass = tr.ReadLine();
            if (pass == password.Text)
            {
                app.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                err.SetError(password, "Password Incorrect");
               // MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Password");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your code continues after your first if statement.

You could either put a `return` in the if statement:

```
if (username.Text == "" && password.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and Password");
    return;
}
```

Or you could change the second if to an `else if`:

```
if (username.Text == "" && password.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and Password");
}
else if (!File.Exists(username.Text + ".txt"))
{
    err.SetError(username, "Username not exist"); //sets the error
    //MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Username");
} else {
  ....
}
```

This way the `!File.Exists` doesn't get executed if the username and password are empty.